# Disadvantage of Constant Memory for Large Convolution Matrixes

Tags: cuda, convolution, gpu-constant-memory

I have been trying to have benefit of constant memory in convolution operations. In 3x3 convolution I can gain little bit speed up but whenever i increase the size of convolution matrix then constant memory support becoming inefficient.

According to its intended use,each thread accesses the same element of convolution matrix at same time in all kernels (3x3, 5x5, 7x7). I have used OpenCV::Mat images(each pixel 8bit unsigned char for gray images).

Question : Why constant memory doesn't accelerate the 5x5 and 7x7 convolution while accelerating the 3x3 convolution ?

Hardware I use : Nvidia GTX 1660 TI (Mobile) with CC 7.5 Turing Arch

There are the kernels :

```
__global__ void k_1D_gf_3x3_default(unsigned char* input, int rows, int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int threadId = (tx * cols + ty);

    unsigned char conv_kernel[3][3] = { {1, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 1} };
    int new_val = 0;

    if ((tx > 0 && tx < rows - 1) && (ty > 0 && ty < cols - 1)) {
        new_val += conv_kernel[0][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel[0][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel[0][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel[1][0] * input[tx * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel[1][1] * input[tx * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel[1][2] * input[tx * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel[2][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel[2][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel[2][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1];

        input[threadId] = new_val / 16;
    }
}

__global__ void k_1D_gf_5x5_default(unsigned char* input, int rows, int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int threadId = (tx * cols + ty);

    unsigned char conv_kernel5x5[5][5] = { {1,  4,  6,  4,  1},
                                    {4, 16, 24, 16,  4},
                                    {6, 24, 36, 24,  6},
                                    {4, 16, 24, 16,  4},
                                    {1,  4,  6,  4,  1} };
    int new_val = 0;

    if ((tx > 1 && tx < rows - 2) && (ty > 1 && ty < cols - 2)) {
        new_val = conv_kernel5x5[0][0] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[0][1] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[0][2] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[0][3] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[0][4] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 2];

        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[1][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[1][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[1][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[1][3] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[1][4] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[2][0] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[2][1] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[2][2] * input[(tx)*cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[2][3] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[2][4] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 2];

        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[3][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[3][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[3][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[3][3] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[3][4] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 2];

        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[4][0] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[4][1] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[4][2] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[4][3] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel5x5[4][4] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 2];

        input[threadId] = new_val / 273;
    }
}

__global__ void k_1D_gf_7x7_default(unsigned char* input, int rows, int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int threadId = (tx * cols + ty);

    unsigned char conv_kernel7x7[7][7] = { {0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0,  0},
                                        {0,  3, 13, 22, 13, 3, 0},
                                        {1, 13, 59, 97, 59, 13, 1},
                                        {2, 22, 97, 159, 97, 22, 2},
                                        {1, 13, 59, 97, 59, 13, 1},
                                        {0,  3, 13, 22, 13, 3, 0},
                                        {0,  0,  1, 2, 1, 0, 0} };
    int new_val = 0;

    if ((tx > 2 && tx < rows - 3) && (ty > 2 && ty < cols - 3)) {
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][0] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][1] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][2] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][3] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][4] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][5] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[0][6] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty + 3];

        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][0] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][1] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][2] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][3] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][4] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][5] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[1][6] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 3];
                
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][3] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][4] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][5] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[2][6] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 3];
                
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][0] * input[(tx) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][1] * input[(tx) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][2] * input[(tx) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][3] * input[(tx) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][4] * input[(tx) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][5] * input[(tx) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[3][6] * input[(tx) * cols + ty + 3];
                
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][3] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][4] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][5] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[4][6] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 3];
                
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][0] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][1] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][2] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][3] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][4] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][5] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[5][6] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 3];
                
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][0] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][1] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][2] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][3] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][4] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][5] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += conv_kernel7x7[6][6] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty + 3];

        input[threadId] = new_val / 1003;
    }
}

__constant__ unsigned char dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[3][3];
__constant__ unsigned char dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[5][5];
__constant__ unsigned char dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[7][7];

__global__ void k_1D_gf_3x3_constant(unsigned char* input, int rows, int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int new_val = 0;

    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[0][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[0][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[0][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[1][0] * input[tx * cols + ty - 1];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[1][1] * input[tx * cols + ty];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[1][2] * input[tx * cols + ty + 1];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[2][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[2][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty];
    new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel3x3[2][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1];

    input[tx * cols + ty] = new_val / 16;
}

__global__ void k_1D_gf_5x5_constant(unsigned char* input, int rows, int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int threadId = (tx * cols + ty);

    int new_val = 0;

    if ((tx > 1 && tx < rows - 2) && (ty > 1 && ty < cols - 2)) {
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[0][0] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[0][1] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[0][2] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[0][3] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[0][4] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 2];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[1][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[1][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[1][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[1][3] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[1][4] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 2];

        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[2][0] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[2][1] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[2][2] * input[(tx)*cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[2][3] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[2][4] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 2];
                  
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[3][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[3][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[3][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[3][3] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[3][4] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 2];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[4][0] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[4][1] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[4][2] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[4][3] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel5x5[4][4] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 2];

        input[threadId] = new_val / 273;
    }
}

__global__ void k_1D_gf_7x7_constant(unsigned char* input, int rows, int cols)
{
    int ty = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tx = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int threadId = (tx * cols + ty);

    int new_val = 0;

    if ((tx > 2 && tx < rows - 3) && (ty > 2 && ty < cols - 3)) {
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][0] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][1] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][2] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][3] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][4] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][5] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[0][6] * input[(tx - 3) * cols + ty + 3];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][0] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][1] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][2] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][3] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][4] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][5] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[1][6] * input[(tx - 2) * cols + ty + 3];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][0] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][1] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][2] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][3] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][4] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][5] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[2][6] * input[(tx - 1) * cols + ty + 3];
                  
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][0] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][1] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][2] * input[(tx)*cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][3] * input[(tx)*cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][4] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][5] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[3][6] * input[(tx)*cols + ty + 3];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][0] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][1] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][2] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][3] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][4] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][5] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[4][6] * input[(tx + 1) * cols + ty + 3];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][0] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][1] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][2] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][3] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][4] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][5] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[5][6] * input[(tx + 2) * cols + ty + 3];
                   
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][0] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty - 3];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][1] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty - 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][2] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty - 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][3] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][4] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty + 1];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][5] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty + 2];
        new_val += dev_const_conv_kernel7x7[6][6] * input[(tx + 3) * cols + ty + 3];

        input[threadId] = new_val / 1003;
    }
}

float gf_1d_gpu(cv::Mat* output_img, GAUSSIAN ver)
{
    unsigned char* gpu_input = nullptr;
    unsigned char* output = output_img->data;

    unsigned int cols = (*output_img).cols;
    unsigned int rows = (*output_img).rows;
    unsigned int size = cols * rows * sizeof(unsigned char);

    unsigned char conv_kernel3x3[3][3] = { {1, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 1} };
    unsigned char conv_kernel5x5[5][5] = {{1, 4,  7,  4,  1},
                                        {4, 16, 26, 16, 4},
                                        {7, 26, 41, 26, 7},
                                        {4, 16, 26, 16, 4},
                                        {1, 4,  7,  4,  1}};
    unsigned char conv_kernel7x7[7][7] = {{0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0,  0},
                                        {0,  3, 13, 22, 13, 3, 0},
                                        {1, 13, 59, 97, 59, 13, 1},
                                        {2, 22, 97, 159, 97, 22, 2},
                                        {1, 13, 59, 97, 59, 13, 1},
                                        {0,  3, 13, 22, 13, 3, 0},
                                        {0,  0,  1, 2, 1, 0, 0}};


    dim3 block(32, 32);
    dim3 grid((cols + block.x - 1) / block.x, (rows + block.y - 1) / block.y);
    dim3 grid2(((cols / 2) + block.x - 1) / block.x, (rows + block.y - 1) / block.y);
    dim3 grid3(((cols / 3) + block.x - 1) / block.x, (rows + block.y - 1) / block.y);
    dim3 grid4(((cols / 4) + block.x - 1) / block.x, (rows + block.y - 1) / block.y);

    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    cudaHostRegister(output, size, cudaHostRegisterPortable);
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc((unsigned char**)&gpu_input, size));
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(gpu_input, output, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    switch (ver)
    {
    default:
        break;
    case GAUSSIAN_3x3_default:
        k_1D_gf_3x3_default << <grid, block >> > (gpu_input, rows, cols);
        break;
    case GAUSSIAN_5x5_default:
        k_1D_gf_5x5_default << <grid, block >> > (gpu_input, rows, cols);
        break;
    case GAUSSIAN_7x7_default:
        k_1D_gf_7x7_default << <grid, block >> > (gpu_input, rows, cols);
        break;
    case GAUSSIAN_3x3_constant:
        CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_const_conv_kernel3x3, conv_kernel3x3, sizeof(unsigned char) * 3 * 3));
        k_1D_gf_3x3_constant << <grid, block >> > (gpu_input, rows, cols);
        break;
    case GAUSSIAN_5x5_constant:
        CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_const_conv_kernel5x5, conv_kernel5x5, sizeof(unsigned char) * 5 * 5));
        k_1D_gf_5x5_constant << <grid, block >> > (gpu_input, rows, cols);
        break;
    case GAUSSIAN_7x7_constant:
        CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_const_conv_kernel7x7, conv_kernel7x7, sizeof(unsigned char) * 7 * 7));
        k_1D_gf_7x7_constant << <grid, block >> > (gpu_input, rows, cols);
        break;
    }
    CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(output, gpu_input, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    float elapsed = 0.0f;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start, stop);

    cudaHostUnregister(output);
    cudaFree(gpu_input);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return elapsed;
}

int main(){
...
..
.

    gray_input_images.push_back(cv::imread(img_path256, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));
    gray_input_images.push_back(cv::imread(img_path512, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));
    gray_input_images.push_back(cv::imread(img_path1024, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));
    gray_input_images.push_back(cv::imread(img_path2048, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));
    gray_input_images.push_back(cv::imread(img_path4096, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));
    gray_input_images.push_back(cv::imread(img_path8192, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));

    float elapsed = 0.0f;

    std::vector <cv::Mat> output1;
    std::vector <cv::Mat> output2;
    std::vector <cv::Mat> output3;
    std::vector <cv::Mat> output4;
    std::vector <cv::Mat> output5;
    std::vector <cv::Mat> output6;
    std::vector <cv::Mat> output7;

    for (cv::Mat& e: gray_input_images) {
        output1.push_back(e.clone());
        output2.push_back(e.clone());
        output3.push_back(e.clone());
        output4.push_back(e.clone());
        output5.push_back(e.clone());
        output6.push_back(e.clone());
        output7.push_back(e.clone());
    }

    for (cv::Mat& e : output2) {
        elapsed += gf_1d_gpu(&e, GAUSSIAN_3x3_default);
    }

    for (cv::Mat& e : output1) {
        elapsed += gf_1d_gpu(&e, GAUSSIAN_5x5_default);
    }


    for (cv::Mat& e : output3) {
        elapsed += gf_1d_gpu(&e, GAUSSIAN_7x7_default);
    }
.
..
...
```

And this is the Nsight Compute output:
[image: Nsight Compute output]

I have tried loop unrolling and converting images to float. Conversion didn't help me in both speed up or better constant memory usage. But as i expected loop unrolling increased the speed up i gain from constant memory.

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Regarding this: "whenever i increase the size of convolution matrix then process is slowing down so hard idk why.", when you increase the size of the convolution matrix, eg. going from 3x3 to 5x5, you are increasing the work that each thread must do dramatically. For example, 3x3 is 9 operations per thread, 5x5 is 25 operations per thread.  Constant memory isn't going to magically make this issue disappear. Even if you use constant memory, you still have more work per thread.

Comment: As u noticed larger matrix means coarsed threads. The point I'm trying to make is, while it's possible to achieve acceleration effects on a 3x3 matrix, why can't the same acceleration be achieved on a 5x5 or 7x7 matrix? The slowdown seems to increase as the matrix size grows.

Comment: please show a complete minimal example code that can be executed

Comment: Your code has a race-condition. There is no guarantee that `input[threadId] = new_val / 1003;` is executed after the threads have read the original value.

Comment: Mr. Abetor, I have uploaded code snippet for your request. I did not understand the race-condition issue btw. How does it happen? Each thread updating distinct pixel (but accessing common pixels). So if you mean there is could be some faulty computation because of any pixel that element of convolution, could be updated by another thread during convolution, this fault could be tolerated for me because of I do not wanna waste time for buffering orginal values via another copy image.

Comment: Regarding the race condition: The same input value is used by multiple threads (all whose window overlaps that index). Nothing in your code stops one thread from writing the output to that index while surrounding threads may still read it. This cannot be solved easily. You need a separate output array.

Comment: Regarding the performance: Note that in the `_default` kernels, the compiler sees the multiplication factors. It can replace the rather expensive integer multiplications with cheaper operations such as `x * 2 == x + x` or `x * 9 == (x << 3) + x`. Floating point convolution with non-trivial coefficients may give you a better comparison

Comment: @Homer512 Many conditions could be solved by fast math functions or a bunch of bit operations as u pointed. But the problem I'm trying to point is "Why constant memory doesn't accelerate the 5x5 and 7x7 convolution while accelerating the 3x3 convolution". As I said the fault caused by race condition is not necessary for my situation.
Also converting uchars to floats doesn't change the situation, even worse.

Comment: Putting this kind of data into constant memory is an optimization when compared to using global memory. When comparing it to a local, known at compile-time array, using constant memory isn't an optimization but a generalization because now you can change the values at runtime. It isn't a fair comparison.

Comment: Your `k_1D_gf_3x3_constant` kernel lacks the range checks that all other kernels do. So comparing it to `k_1D_gf_3x3_default` is already flawed. To me, it's not surprising that a smaller kernel is more sensitive to launch overhead and other secondary effects while a larger kernel is more sensitive to compute throughput, therefore profits more from the constant folding that the `_default` kernels allow.

Comment: Thx for pointing that @Homer512. Probably I forgot about it. I implemented this range control, still works faster than local memory. Even if i didn't share with you comparison of global vs. constant, as u guess constant is more efficient in all situations. Anyway, thanks a lot paleonix, Homer512, Abator and Robert for sharing your ideas and trying to help.